# На фидле код работает, а у меня нет.

Tags: jquery

То есть у меня просто видео проигрывается и под видео время не считается и не останавливается само. Так что почему-то jquery не работает или что-то ещё. Но вот [фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/fKfgp/22/) и в нем код работает, а вот как я у себя его запускаю [тык](http://pastebin.com/ehUaWZBn)

Не пойму в чем проблема. Уже пробовал по разному подключать jquery(и себе скачивал, и от гугла ссылку брал, и от офф сайта). Так же клацал по файлу jquery в исходном коде и на него нормально заходило.

Comment: Заработало. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оберните код в

```
$(function (){   /* ваш код */ });
```

фидл делает это по умолчанию, там слева есть настройка, как подключить ваш код: `onLoad, onDomready, in head, in body. $(function (){ /* ваш код */ }); — onDomready`